# Parameter in the url, I need to keep it as is. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular ui-router to redirect views. Currently someone from backend provides me with a url with an encrypted password.

http://localhost:8010/project/#!/restaurar/%2b490OW%2bY5sVvma1hR64DW%2fMv89sDCngf

The idea is that the url provided by this person, I can open it in my project, and can receive the password as a parameter. (in this case is: %2b490OW%2bY5sVvma1hR64DW%2fMv89sDCngf)

So I have the routes configured.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

.state('restaurar', {
  url: "/restaurar/:token",
  templateUrl: 'Client/views/restaurar.html',
  controller: 'LandingController'
})
```

But when I receive this parameter, I redirect to the root state "/", if I try with any other parameter, it works without problem. I need this encrypted password to keep it as it is, or at least keep it unchanged in the controller.

if I write in the url for example:

http://localhost:8010/project/#!/restaurar/a text

it works...my template is loaded.

http://localhost:8010/project/#!/restaurar/a%20text

simply I put that Url in the browser..The backend returns a link, when clicking on this link, it takes me to the url that I have put.

How can I make this encrypted password keep unchanged, and allow me to redirect to my view?

The most important thing is to keep the password as it is received, and to allow me to go to my template.

Comment: Have you tried storing it in a `rootScope` variable ?

Comment: Is the token url encoded ?

Comment: @elpddev yes, the parameter(%2b490OW%2bY5sVvma1hR64DW%2fMv89sDCngf) is encoded..

Comment: @CamiloR I never can receibe the parameter..... I am redirected to "/"

Comment: How do you get the parameter ? Is the angular app already loaded in the browser and you do an $http.get ajax request to get the url from the server and then use it in `$state.go(url)` ?

Comment: I am sure the problem is that space (%20). It causing your ui-router to throw 404, that's why it redirects to index.

Comment: @elpddev  no, simply I put that Url in the browser..The backend returns a link, when clicking on this link, it takes me to the url that I have put.

Comment: @yBrodsky yes yes yes! I think the same, with another parameter I can normally go to view. But with this parameter(%2b490OW%2bY5sVvma1hR64DW%2fMv89sDCngf), perhaps the "%" causes the conflict. And therefore I can not go to the template.

Comment: Try changin your route definition so that it's a query param. url: 'restaurar?token'

Comment: Also, try this: url: 'restaurar/{token:any}'

Comment: @yBrodsky I already have, but it does not solve my problem, the parameter changes.  'restaurar?token'

Comment: `%2f` is a `/` ... your encoding needs changing

Comment: @charlietfl %2f is / ????